# How to escape '/' in channel name in Rfhutil?

Tags: escaping, ibm-mq

I'm trying to put message to a queue, using Rfhutil.
Channel name is: AA.BB/CC

So my connection string looks like this:
*AA.BB/CC/TCP/somehost.com(5555)*

Is it possible to escape '/'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if MQ cannot handle the MQSERVER environment variable with a '/' in the channel name (odd but maybe true) then you will need to use a CCDT (Client Channel Definition Table) file.